# How can I setup a listener for SBMediaVolumeChangedNotification?

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications

I have an app that uses the darwin notify center.

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                NULL, // observer
                                displayStatusChanged, // callback
                                CFSTR("com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

I would really like to capture volume button presses in the background. I found these notifications listed

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SpringBoard.app/Notifications

Is there a way to trigger methods on SBMediaVolumeChangedNotification?

Answer (score 0):

The SBMediaVolumeChangedNotification is not a Darwin notification, it is a default local notification. To capture it, you would need a common notification observer, like this one (in Swift):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "volumeChanged:", name: "SBMediaVolumeChangedNotification", object: nil)
```

However, the documentation states that:

> The object is an SBMediaController instance.

So I think we would need to pass a SBMediaController instance to the observer, as the object, to make it work. Since the SBMediaController class seems to be inaccessible from the SDK, I don't think there is a way to use that specific notification. I have tried without the object, but it didn't work for me.